# Increase debugging variable hover mouse-off delay Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-community

I can hover over any variable with a mouse but to view it if it's a large string I have to move the mouse over and click on the magnifying glass which is like a minor tight-rope walk occasionally for simple string variables.

Is there some way to increase the hover-off timer such that if I mouse-off before my mouse reaches the magnifying glass, I don't have to start all over?

Comment: Especially when this is a situation, where you repeatedly need to see the same variable(s), you could pin data tips to your source code (see [View data values in Data Tips in the code editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd.aspx)). This feature was introduced in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hovering, you can bring up a **Quick Watch** (either right click and Quickwatch or with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>):

[image]

Alternatively you can also use the **Locals** window.  It'll be a bit more work to find the particular variable you're looking for, but at least it wont collapse:

[image]